# Magento 1 : Showing chines text in var/sessoin file

Tags: magento-1.9, session

Is there any idea about why some file are showing chines text in var/session ?

Comment: may be its being hacked.

Comment: If you clear var/session do the files regenerate?  Are you using any bespoke extension to handle sessions?

Comment: yes its regenerate and bespoke extension means ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your site is hacked. Please clear all sessions and caches. Upgrade your files using this command :

> php bin/magento setup:upgrade

If after this process, you did see same problem, please restore your backup.